# Multiple background repeat in sequence

Tags: html, css

How can I make multiple background images in sequence?

By doing the following, the images just overlaps and it doesn't display in sequence

```
img {
background-image: "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", image3.jpg";
background-repeat: repeat-y, repeat-y, repeat-y;
}
```

What I want to do is...
image1
image2
image3
image1
image2
image3
and so on..

Comment: Do you mean you want to have a background image displayed for a while and then fade out and fade in another? That would be JS or Jquery.

Comment: you could create a image sprite and just apply one background.

Answer (score 1):

MDN has a good read on [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds).

If you want to repeat the backgrounds in sequence, i.e.

```
img01 img02 img03 img01 img02 img03
img01 img02 img03 img01 img02 img03
img01 img02 img03 img01 img02 img03
img01 img02 img03 img01 img02 img03
```

you may need to cheat. You can specify different orientations for each background image, but I don't think this extends to mixing tiling patterns. The positioning is restricted to plain old `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` and pixel values for single instances etc...

What you could do it save each image at the size of the tile you wish to repeat, and leave the space for the other images transparent. Imagine these lines are each an image lining up vertically

```
|img01              |
|      img02        |
|             img03 |
```

When the 3 images overlap, you will see each one through the others. This will generate the tiling effect. You can then simply specify:

```
background:repeat, repeat, repeat;
```

The overlapping images will tile as per normal, but the overlapping will make them look like this:

```
|img01 img02 img03|img01 img02 img03|
|img01 img02 img03|img01 img02 img03|
```

Comment: The size of the images are different. I get the idea but it doesn't work on mine.

Comment: If it's a tiling pattern, it should be able to work. It doesn't matter if the images are different sizes, because the overall tile will be a constant size. Just allow the appropriate amount of space for each background image.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: @Mayank Tripathi had a good suggestion above, if it's got to tile, why not simply use a single background image containing all your desired backgrounds? Why go to the trouble of trying to CSS it into place if Photoshop does it for you?